# Return count of matching List items without iterating (java)

Tags: java, list, counting

The only answer thought of was recursion or somehow converting a List to a string, but given a List of strings, e.g.

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a,b,a,c,d,e,a".split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

How would you find the number of occurances of a specific value in any kind of List without using iteration (I presume you can ignore how library methods work), e.g. in the above 'a' would have a value of 3.

Yes, this was an interview question :)

Comment: pointless question imho as you have to inspect each list item anyway to be sure. whether or not to call the process of visiting 'iteration' is merely a matter of taste.

Comment: Maybe `("a,b,a,c,d,e,a".length() - "a,b,a,c,d,e,a".replace("a","").length) / "a".length`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How can each element be inspected without iterating over the collection? To avoid explicitly coding the iteration could use [`Collections.frequency()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) which:

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).

Answer (score 2):

This would be a recursive solution, as always prone to stack overflows and not really a great choice in Java. But since interviewers *love* recursion, here it goes :)

```
int countOccurences(List<T> l, T x) {
  return l.isEmpty()? 0 
   : (l.get(0).equals(x)? 1 : 0) + countOccurrences(l.subList(1, l.length()), x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do:

```
int countInCollection(List<T> list, T toFind) {
  int count = 0;
  while (list.remove(toFind)) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer I'm not explicitly iterating over the collection.